# centered button in a fixed width div shifts to left in ipad

Tags: html, ios, css

There is a button in a div, surrounded by `<section>`:

```
<div id="body">
    <section>
        <div class="area">
            <button>Hello!</button>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

The `#body`, its `<section>` have a fixed width and the `.area` have a 50px padding:

```
#body{
width:600px;
margin:0 auto;
background:#eee;
}
section{
width:300px;
margin:0 auto;
background:#FFF;
}
.area{
padding:50px;
}
button {
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Everything is done in my monitor, and the button is centered perfectly. But on ipad it shifts to left:

[image]

You can see this case in action: **http://jsfiddle.net/c2HLe/**

Comment: You don't have any media queries do you?

Comment: I don't have an iPad so I can't test the following.  Maybe the `.area` element needs a width, why don't you add `width: inherit` and see if that solves it.  The iPad browser may handle default widths differently than other browsers.

Comment: `width: inherit` shifts the button to right in the monitor and ipad shifts it to left yet

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use a CSS reset, you might want to try it to see if there is some browser standard messing up your layout.